# Android JUNIT Get Keyboard View

Tags: android, testing, junit, keyboard

I am (trying) to test a Keyboard App via JUnit.

So there are three applications,

- Keyboard Application
- Memo Application (Just a app with one EditText)
- JUnit Application for Memo App

How do I obtain the keyboard context or view from the JUnit application.
findViewById() from the JUnit scope does not work, and seems like the InputMethodManager does not support such a functionality.

Any insight is welcome, thank you! (Sorry for the noob Q!)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you would like to test the user interface of your Keyboard Application I'd like to say the following: in general **unit testing** user interfaces is rather uncommon since you actually have to run the application in order to automate let's say a button click.

There are other tools to do (graphical) user interface testing like *Selenium* for testing websites. Unfortunately I don't know any GUI testing framework for Android but I'm sure there is one.

Generally speaking, try to put as little business logic code into user interface related code as you can, so you can unit test business logic separately. To summarize, testing a graphical user interface with a unit testing framework like JUnit is not a good idea.